# How to find one id with, two same variables and different values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have to get ID by two values. 
So let's say when i call: id - 2 i get two values 7 and 6.
I want to call 7 and 6 to get value 2

i have table **recipeingredient** where i should find **recipe_id 2** using **ingredient_id 6** and **7**

example:

```
SELECT * FROM recipeingredient WHERE recipe_id=2
```

**returns: 6 7**

but i want reversed.

i think it should be equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM recipeingredient WHERE ingredient_id=6 AND ingredient_id=7
```

**should return: 2** but returns nothing

to sum up: 
on my php web page, i have to select 2 elements and get 1 displayed value.
its TAG system. i cant use OR, i need to get value that has as value A so value B.

Comment: An in ingredient cannot be both 6 and 7 at the same time

Comment: Think about this logically. A single ingredient in a recipe cannot be both _salt_ and _pepper_ at the same time, but it can be either _**or**_. You simply need to replace `AND` with `OR` to make it check for _either_ `6` _or_ `7`: `SELECT * FROM recipeingredient WHERE ingredient_id=6 OR ingredient_id=7`

Comment: so my friend built this db for group project. 
i just need to select 2 values and get data. OR wont help. i will edit my question

Comment: @DrSkull no need you have to valid answers from gmb and scaisedge.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that part of your question. Anyway, as P.Salmon said you've got two good and valid answers now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a HAVING clause to implement the filter, like :

```
SELECT recipe_id
FROM recipeingredient
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING 
    SUM(ingredient_id=6) > 0
    AND SUM(ingredient_id=7) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a recipe that contains the two ingredients

you could use IN 
and chek for just 2 ingredient

```
    SELECT id 
    FROM recipeingredient 
    WHERE ingredient_id IN (6 ,7)
    group by id 
    having count(distinct ingredient_id ) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually want this:

```
-- all recipes that could be prepared with 6 and/or 7
SELECT recipe_id
FROM recipeingredient
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ingredient_id IN (6, 7) THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
```

Or this:

```
-- all recipes that could be prepared with exactly 6 and 7
SELECT recipe_id
FROM recipeingredient
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ingredient_id IN (6, 7) THEN 1 END) = 2
AND COUNT(*) = 2
```

Both queries skip recipes that require an ingredient other than 6 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM recipeingredient WHERE ingredient_id=6 OR ingredient_id=7
```

AND will show you results when both conditions are true. You should use OR to check for both values for same column. A row cannot have two values for same column at the same time.

Comment: This will return any recipe which as 6 or 7 but not necessarily where the recipe has both 6 and 7

Answer (score 0):

How can an ingredient be at the same time be 6 and 7 (unless your data is non structural or deliminated non atomic values) thats why while using `AND` clause you received o/p as `no rows selected`.

Better option is to use `IN` or `OR` clause both are almost similar but `IN` would avoid usage of again and again writing as its a function with parameters and not an operator like `OR`

```
    SELECT * FROM recipeingredient 
    WHERE ingredient_id IN (6,7)
       --using IN clause



     SELECT * FROM recipeingredient 
     WHERE ingredient_id=6 OR 
       ingredient_id=7
     -- using OR
```